# how can I get a callback from googleplus popup's button share action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-plus, share

I need to run an event when user's share my web's post on gplus... but I don't find any way to do this even looking at the API'S documentation

Here's the share button's code

```
<g:plus action="share"></g:plus>
<script>
      window.___gcfg = {
        lang: 'en-US',
        parsetags: 'onload'
      };

    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The share button does not post any event unless you have to authorize with the google plus .FOA you have to implement the google auth for g+ users using the [link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth). After authorization you will be given a unique access_token that can be used to post event in gplus for the particular user. The implementation can be find in the [link](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating#creating_a_post). If you successfully post in g+, you will get an json response from g+ regarding the post you were shared. So by this response you can confirm the post is shared and you can run you event . I hope this will helpul to you.